# Matching parenthesis with recursion and stacks

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to figure out how to write this code using recursion. I have done it sing for loops but have absolutely no clue how to use recursion here. I am new to code.Thanks for stopping by and helping.
P.S.
Sorry if i didnt explain what this does. The objective is to find out how many matching pairs of parenthesis exist in a given string input. It should also return -1 if a set is unbalanced.
These are the instructions
Classes names.

MatchingBracesFirstNameLastName.java
Stack.java
Description.

Write a program to match parenthesis (), square braces [] and curly braces {}. Your program should use a recursive method that returns the number of pairs of each type of brace and return -1 if it is unbalanced for a particular pair. You should also create a Stack class that will be used by the method to match braces.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatchingBraces
{
   public static void main(String []args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      String text = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println(match(text, '(', ')', 0));
      System.out.println(match(text, '[', ']', 0));
      System.out.println(match(text, '{', '}', 0));
   }

   public static int match(String text, char open, char close, int startIndex)
   {  
      Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
      int count = 0;
      char c;
      for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
      {
         c = text.charAt(i);
         if(c == open)
            stack.push(c);

         if(c == close)
         {
            if(stack.empty())
               return count;
            else if(stack.peek() == open)
            {
               stack.pop();
               count++;
            }
         }
      }
     return count;
   }
}
```

Comment: Javascript, seriously?

Comment: what do you mean? Like i said new so im using java and jgrasp. sounded like that was the right thing so thats what i clicked

Comment: it seems that the original tag was java script!

Comment: That was probably a mistake just due to my ignorance about such things. Sorry if that confused anyone.

Comment: at least tell us what this code do.

Comment: note the code the you have currently written does not return -1 for unbalanced. and it is maintaining a pointless stack of Characters when a numberOpened would suffice

Comment: @PatrickParker: Sure, if you just need the count, just count all the open chars and all the close chars, and compare the counts. If you don't care about what's inside the parentheses then the problem is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would redefine the part of the problem that is recursive (or stack-oriented, they're isomorphic). You are scanning an input string and you want to count the number of balanced pairs of tokens.

So you can break this up into two sub-problems:

1. Find every open character in the string, and check that it has a matching close character.
2. Given the location of an open character, find the location of the matching close character.

Both problems could be implemented recursively, but problem #2 is more naturally a recursive problem. This is because the problem is naturally nested: while you're finding the matching close character for one pair, if you encounter a new open character, you need to first find the matching close character for *it* before going back to finding the current matching close character. This is a classic inductive or recursive way of formulating a problem.

If you're OK with a bit more complexity, you can solve both problems at once by formulating your sub-problem as:

- Given the location of an open character, return both the location of the corresponding closing character and the number of pairs of open/close contained within that pair, if any.

The reason I wouldn't jump to that second option right now is because returning two values opens up a number of other questions. You could use an external state variable, or introduce a new class to represent the two values. It adds complexity, but ultimately adding a new type here is probably the best overall solution.

I don't want to do your homework for you, but hopefully this helps you to see what your next steps need to be. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: so would it be broken up into two methods?? one for the open char and another for close? sorry i am really confused about this stuff.

Comment: If I were writing this for real, I would use at least two methods. I would probably use a small private class for holding state and have my parse method be an instance method of that, and just use the static method as a public API. And if I were doing this for real, I wouldn't use a recursive solution unless I was sure the nesting depth had a reasonable limit. I'd probably use an iterative solution with a manual stack (in Java, I mean; not in some other languages). In the real world, you write code to solve a problem, and you don't rewrite working code unless it solves a problem.

Comment: tell that to my programming professor. I honestly dont know where to go from here and the liang book isnt a great help. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the current method signature doesn’t contain enough information for a straightforward recursive solution, so I would add a helper method that returns two pieces of information: 1. the stack count for the next open starting from startIndex, and 2. the position of the last char processed.

You need this second piece of information so that the caller can continue where the recursive call left off.

**Helper Logic:**

Beginning at startIndex, proceed to the right until you encounter either an open or a close or end of input.

If you encounter a close first, return -1 for count. If end of input, 0. If you encounter an open first, proceed.

If you encounter an open next, initiate a subcall. Check the subcall for -1 and abort if so. Otherwise, update a local variable which records the max stacks count returned by any subcall thus far. Proceed to the next unprocessed character location.

If you encounter end of input next, return -1 for count.

If you encounter a close next, return 1 + maxOfSubcalls.

Note: it may be necessary for the main routine to invoke the helper again if end of input was not reached. in that case maxOfHelper would be returned, assuming no -1’s.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by intiating a subcall if you dont mind me asking

Comment: @Megamind7777 by “subcall” I am mean when the helper recursively calls itself.